# Como converter sysdate para milisegundos no Oracle?

Tags: sql, query, oracle

Como converter `sysdate` para `milisegundos` diretamente no Oracle?

Preciso que dê o mesmo resultado do código abaixo em java, porém diretamente na *query*:

```java
String s=df.format(Calendar.getInstance());
java.util.Date parsedUtilDate = df.parse(s);  
java.sql.Timestamp timestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(parsedUtilDate.getTime());
long timeInMilliSeconds = timestamp.getTime();
```

Comment: Qual o problema da pergunta?

Answer (score 1):

Basenando-se [nessa resposta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12105907/540552), primeiro você deve criar esta função:

```sql
create or replace function date_to_unix_ts( PDate in date ) return number is

   l_unix_ts number;

begin

   l_unix_ts := ( PDate - date '1970-01-01' ) * 60 * 60 * 24;
   return l_unix_ts;

end;
```

Depois você a utiliza assim:

```sql
select date_to_unix_ts(systimestamp) from dual;
```

Se você quiser tentar fazer sem precisar da função, talvez isso funcione:

```sql
select ((systimestamp - date '1970-01-01') * 60 * 60 * 24) as t from dual;
```

Entretanto, tal como [explanado nesta outra resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13187536/540552), isso não leva em conta o fuso horário e o horário de verão.